# MSB6004 error in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to start programming Android with C# but in my first program I have this error:

> "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error
>
> MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Users\briluser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe" is invalid. (MSB6004)"

I found  the android-sdk directory on my system, and copied zipalign from the build-tools/19.1.0 directory to the tools directory but it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before and manually copying the file doesn't seem to work.  To work around this try going into the Android SDK Manager and expanding the `Tools` folder.  In there, try installing the latest version of the `Android SDK Build-tools`.  For me this is Rev. 20.  After installing the update, this error should go away.